# How to calculate percentage in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which I have multiple IDs which can have a value or 0. The IDs come from different sources so I would like to know what is the percentage of IDs with the value 0 as a percentage of total IDs, for each source file.

Sample Data:

```
ID  Source    
1    aaa     
0    aaa     
2    bbb     
0    ccc     
3    ccc     
0    ccc 
5    aaa 
0    bbb
6    bbb 
7    bbb
```

I need to display Output like:

```
CountOfIDs0   TotalIDs Source  PercentageIDs0
2               3         ccc     66.6%%
1               3         aaa     33.3%%
1               4         bbb     25%
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Comment: So, do you know how to populate the `COUNT` columns and you are only interested in the `PERCENTAGE` column? Oracle doesn't have a special function for that; if `A` and `B` are two numbers, you calculate the percentage as `ROUND(A/B*100, 1)` and if you want to display it with a percent sign you can use `TO_CHAR()` and concatenate with `'%'`

Comment: I have gotten this far                                                                       `select  round(a/b, 2)*100 percent from (select count(ID) a from table 
where ID> 0 
group by source), (select count(ID) b from table group by source)`; But I am getting really wacky results (above 100%). And in this form I cannot see the source.

Comment: @mathguy, I am also interested in getting the `COUNT`. I have figured how to display the counts individually, but I am yet to figure out how to display both of them in a query.

Comment: Yes, I noticed and I addressed that in my Answer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a result like 66.6% rather than 66.7%, you would use `trunc()` rather than `round()` (although the latter is probably better). And you need to round a/b to three decimal places, so there is one left after you multiply by 100.

Then, you can have both counts in one query, and you can add the percentage calculation also in the same query.

```
select count(case when propkey = 0 then 1 end) countid0,
       count(propkey) totalidcount,
       source,
       to_char(round(count(case when properkey = 0 then 1 end)/count(properkey), 3)*100) 
                                                                   || '%' percentageids0
from......
```

Comment: One little `GROUP BY` at the end and this works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @mathguy (\*coughs\* you've got the `*100` in the wrong place; it needs to go inside the `round(...)`, preferably after (or before) the `count(case when... end)`)

Comment: I think the law of maximum embarrassment applies to the combination of the original answer and the screen name of the person posting it.

Comment: @Boneist - I had the *100 in the right place but was missing a closing ). I followed the OP's lead in dividing, rounding to three decimal places and only then multiplying; as you will see in Comments to the original post, my inclination is to multiply by 100 and only then to round... I was somewhat careless when I wrote the solution.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Not sure what you mean... ?

Comment: @mathguy ah right; of course - duh - I missed the fact that you were rounding to 3dp not the 1 that I had in my answer which would have been similar to yours. I'll get my coat...

Comment: @boniest - MY answer had the *100 first and then the rounding - until I started typing and noticed what the OP was doing. Since her formula was equally valid, I used it - no reason to impose "my" way of computing over a perfectly fine but different one.

Comment: [getting my popcorn] This is entertaining :D. My bad on the `*100`, but the results are the same, so it should not hurt anyone, no?

Comment: @AnnaB - Why "my bad" - there is absolutely nothing wrong with doing it that way (except, as I pointed out, you need to round to three places if you then multiply by 100 and want one decimal place left). Unusual, yes, but not wrong.

Comment: @Boneist, that's why I said my bad. My typing is atrocious, and I put 2 instead of 3 without noticing. Plus, putting the 100 where I did was the only way I thought of, so you should have corrected me instead. But anyways, thanks for a useful other option :).

Comment: @AnnaB I hadn't seen your comment on the question when I came to add my answer, only Mathguy had gotten there first. I shouldn't have said anything, perhaps!

Comment: how can I get 80% of some value in oracle ?

Answer (score 2):

Apply `round` function.

```
 select count(id) as TotalIDs ,Source, sum(case when id=0 then 1 end) countid0,
        to_char((sum(case when id=0 then 1 end)/count(id))*100)||'%' as PercentageIDs0
     from Table1 group by Source
```

Comment: why would the OP need to make sure the column is in float? NUMBER is a perfectly good datatype to use. Also, I suspect your answer is based on some other platform than Oracle?

Comment: Ho my mistake. I was confused with sql server. And removed that line. Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to remove the square brackets to allow this to run in Oracle.

Comment: @Boneist Updated post.

Answer (score 0):

For Unique record you have to use DISTINCT Query

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question the OP asked, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way:

```
With MyRows AS (
  SELECT 1 ID, 'aaa' SOURCE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'ccc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'ccc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'ccc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 'bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'bbb' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT 
  DISTINCT SOURCE,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE) ZERO_IDS,
  COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE) TOTAL_IDS,
  (100 * SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE))/(COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE)) PERCENTAGE
FROM MyRows
;
```

Comment: I am not sure this would work well for a few million distinct IDs :D

Comment: @am2 Well, you could. But why would you use analytic functions and distinct when you could achieve the same thing (using less typing) with a bog-standard aggregate query?

Comment: @Boneist: it is easier to read if written, at least for me. If I - maybe years later - put my eyes on the query I w/o problems understand it.  Each column is readable for its own and as far as I tried these functions are very fast because they start to work when the whole data is taken. Since I very often have queries with at least 10 tables involved I know, that the oracle mechanisms can become very slow, if you change things. analytic functions are always fast.

Comment: @AnnaB: I am sure. Whenever I could replace `group by` by analytic functions my queries became faster. Maybe it is only my situation, I work on a very very very normalized database.

Comment: Another reason I did not mention: the example is to small for it, but often I get change requests, that don't match the query and the `group by`.

Comment: if you have f.e. one more column and you Need something like that: `SELECT 
  DISTINCT SOURCE, XY,
  COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE) TOTAL_IDS,
  COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE, XY) TOTAL_IDSXY
FROM MyRows`

Comment: @am2 - I may believe that analytic functions will be faster than grouping - but there's no way they will remain faster when you need to add DISTINCT to your SELECT.

Comment: @mathguy: you are right as long as distinct is not a way to avoid more complicated queries. f.e. SELECT A

Comment: @mathquy (cannot change my own comment, invested my reputation in a query): **`SELECT DISTINCT ABC, SUM(CDE) OVER (PARTITION BY ABC), SUM(CDE) OVER (), 100 * SUM (CDE) OVER (PARTITION BY ABC) / SUM (CDE) OVER () FROM XYZ`**

Answer (score 0):

I calculated percentage of values in a column by using below query

Select A.*,B.*, to_char((A.count_service/B.count_total)*100)||'%' from
(Select type_cd, count(type_cd) as count_type
from table1
group by type_cd) A
cross join
(Select count(type_cd) as count_total
from table1) B ;

Answer (score -1):

select Source,
ROUND(100*number/sum(number) OVER (PARTITION BY p),2) as percentage,
sum(number) OVER (PARTITION BY p) as total
from(
select 1 p,
Source ,
count(Source) number
from declaration_assessment_result
GROUP by Source
)x

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers.  Include text that explains the code and how it answers the question.